# RISC V LD error - (.text+0xc4): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_JAL against `*UND*'

Tags: riscv

Does any body has clue why I get below error :-

```
       /tmp/cceP5axg.o: in function `.L0 ':

      (.text+0xc4): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_JAL against `*UND*'

       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Typical error looks like:

```
relocation R_RISCV_JAL out of range: 4734022 is not in [-1048576, 1048575];
```

Comment: If you give some context for how you reached that error message, it will be a lot easier to explain the reason for it. For example, if you are compiling C and C++ together, you might be missing an `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 2):

R_RISCV_JAL relocation can represent an even signed 21-bit offset (-1MiB to +1MiB-2). If your symbol is further than this limit , then you have this error.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen as an odd result of branch instructions that use hard-coded offsets. I was getting the same exact error on a program that was far less than 2Mib. It turns out it was because I had several instructions that looked like `bne rd, rs, offset`, but the offset was a number literal like 0x8.

The solution was to remove the literal offset and replace it with a label from the code so it looks like

```
bne x7, x9, branch_to_here
[code to skip]
branch_to_here:
    more code ...
```

instead of

```
bne x7, x9, 0x8
[code to skip]
more code ...
```

When I did that to every branch instruction, the error went away. Sorry to answer this 10 months late, but I hope it helps you, anonymous reader.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've searched many resources to solve this issue, I think my attempt may help others.
There're 2 reasons may trigger this issue:

1. The target address is an odd:
   `bne ra, ra, <odd offset>`
2. The target address is a specific value during compile time (not linking):
   `bne ra, ra, 0x80003000`

My attempt to solve:

```
label:
  addi x0, x0, 0x0
  addi x0, x0, 0x0       
  bne ra, ra, label + 6 // Jump to an address that relates to a label
                        // This can generate Instruction Address Misaligned exception
sub_label:
  addi x0, x0, 0x0
  beq ra, ra, sub_label // Jump to a label directly
  addi x0, x0, 0x0
  nop
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to try building with optimization flag (e.g., -O2 or -O3 as suggested in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111420#c3)

I've opened a bug with binutils for tracking this issue:https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30855